# Failed to open stream Autoload.php in logs after I removed the package

Tags: log, app

I manually removed a package that I had manually installed a couple years ago so that I could replace it with a new package. Right now when I click on a product in Catalog (in Admin view) the following error throws:

```
2017-02-14T14:26:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Elasticsearch/Model/Attribute/Source/Weight.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-02-14T14:26:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Elasticsearch/Model/Attribute/Source/Weight.php' for inclusion (include_path='/html/app/code/local:/html/app/code/community:/html/app/code/core:/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Note: I removed prefixes to some of the paths as it includes my site's url.

I've purged the cache and confirmed that there are no files left over that would trigger this. Any ideas of where I should look to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize there was a db entry for this module. I went to eav_attribute and delete the entry and now everything is working properly.